# error in vba excel textbox when cancelled

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub search()

Columns("J:K").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotSelect "device[All]", xlLabelOnly _
    + xlFirstRow, True

Cells.Find(What:=InputBox("Please enter the PartID", "Search"), _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True

Selection.Copy
Sheets("interface").Select
Range("L501").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("J:K").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A2").Select




 End Sub
```

I have this code on my sub button but there is an error when i cancel the input box that shows.. the error is: "Unable to set the ShowDetail property of the Range class".the error highlighted is:

```
 Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes because it doesn't find anything. You can trap the error in many ways, one of which would be:

```
Sub search()
dim sPartID as string
Columns("J:K").Hidden = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotSelect "device[All]", xlLabelOnly _
    + xlFirstRow, True

sPartID=InputBox("Please enter the PartID", "Search")
if len(sPartID)=0 then exit sub

Cells.Find(What:=sPartID, _
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).ShowDetail = True

Selection.Copy Sheets("interface").Range("L501")

Columns("J:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir.. but another problem is when i cancel the inputbox.. columns J and K dont hide.. i inserted a code like this 
     Columns("J:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
     Range("A2").Select